# When using the GCP OS Login TRUE, is it possible to access SSH from outside through Putty or VSCODE? How?

Tags: ssh, putty, gcp, external-connection

As I understood that, If I enable the GCP OS Login for the project, the normal behavior to SSH using public keys in metadata will cease to work.

I am curious about the SSH connection method using an external terminal(putty) or code when activating the OS Login function.